# Reload wifi adapter when no internet connection

Tags: raspbian, wifi, server

So it seems that my raspian which is online via a wifi adapter is loosing its connection from time to time. Usually a powercycle helps an everything is back normal.

Now to avoid that i would like to regulary check if internet connection is available via a cronjob and if it is not, i would like to reload the wifi adapter.

How can i do that?

Comment: raspi is not a wearable platform. you should have used the ethernet, cable is cheap.

Comment: ethernet cable is not possible here.

Comment: Maybe the wifi adapter should be connected via a USB hub. The current drain on the Pi could be causing the connection to drop?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to test this becuase all of my pis are headless, but you may be able to reset the wifi adapter by doing `ifdown wlan0` followed by `ifup wlan0`.